# Angular.js ngTable select input as a column not showing the existing value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable, angularjs-model

I'm using Angular.js 1.2 and I'm trying to use a Select input in the cell of an ngTable. The Option list populates but the ngModel directive doesn't seem to select the item for display.

This is what my table looks like at the moment:

```
    <table class="col-xs-12 table" data-ng-table>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="task in template.tasks">
            <td data-title="'Category'">
                <select class="form-control template-task-category" data-ng-model="task.categoryId" data-ng-options="category.description for category in taskCategories track by category.id"></select>
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Description'">
                <input class="form-control template-task-description center-block" data-ng-model="task.description"/>
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Default Role'">
                <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="task.defaultRoleId" data-ng-options="role.Name for role in roles track by role.id"></select>
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Est. Hours'">
                <input class="form-control template-task-hours center-block" data-ng-model="task.estimatedHours"/></td>
            <td data-title="'Order'"><input class="form-control template-task-sort center-block" data-ng-model="task.sortOrder"/>
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Remove'">
                <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" onclick="return false;" data-ng-click="removeTask(task)"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

The Category and Default Role columns always show as un-selected dropdowns, and when I display the `task.categoryId` and `task.defaultRoleId` directly they do have values that are part of the Options list. Is there something more I need to do here?

**Edit**

Here's an example. What I was expecting was for the dropdowns to have the associated value selected. http://plnkr.co/edit/9DkSQT?p=preview

Comment: Have you tried putting the group by into your selects that are using track by?

Comment: Nevermind. Playing with the plnkr on Angular seems that this isn't required. Should they be selected from task.categories and task.roles? It's really hard to tell without you putting this in a working plnkr or fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The ng-model needed to point at a full instance of the associated object and not just the property that held the id. In my class I had both an Id field (that mimicked the database table) and the associated instance. Binding to the instance (task.taskCategory instead of task.categoryId) fixed it.